# addSubview lag?

Tags: ios, animation, subview, lag

I am trying to do custom animations between view controllers and in the case below I am doing a mimicking of UINavigationController's popViewController. However, it seems to lag a lot on iPhones and especially iPads and Time Profiler confirms it saying that all of the lag comes from the addSubview line.

Anyway, I connect nlView via Interface Builder and I use the code below:

```
    [self.view.superview addSubview:nlView.view];
    [nlView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-kWidth, 20, kWidth, kHeight-20)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                     animations:^{
                         [nlView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, kWidth, kHeight-20)];
                         [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(kWidth, 20, kWidth, kHeight-20)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
```

So, how could I minimize this lag to nothing at all? There are no leaks or anything like that but how could I just change my logic so that there is no lag when changing views?

Thanks!

Comment: Call `setFrame:` on  `nlView.view` before adding it as subview. This may help because in this case the `drawRec:` method of nlView will be called only once

Comment: Did that but still not too much better specifically on the iPad. The iPhone version of the app seems OK. What else could I do to alleviate the lag?

Comment: One more thing that you can do to improve this is to calculate `kHeight-20` before using it in `animateWithDuration:` like this: `float dH = kHeight - 20` then use it in `[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{[nlView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, kWidth, dH)];...`

Comment: A little better but still a lot of lag left. Anything else I could do? Could I cache my UIViewControllers or something? It seems that the bulk of the lag is coming from the setFrame line.

Comment: If you want to animate just the view's position so instead of setting the frame, animate the view's layer position like this: `[nlView.view.layer setPosition: newPosition]...` of course you need to add QuartzCore to your project and import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

Comment: What is the difference of doing this vs setFrame? Will it change the way things behave in my app?

Comment: yes I think it might help give it a try :)

Comment: And I still do addSubview:myView or no? How about the removeFromSuperview line? Keep that also?

Comment: Yes, you add the subview and then animate the layer position instead of view frame. Your other code remains the same

Comment: Alright thanks, if you post this as an answer I will accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to animate the view's position then instead of setting the frame, animate the view's layer position like this: `[nlView.view.layer setPosition: newPosition]...` of course you need to add QuartzCore to your project and import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h